# How do I lock a table to prevent record creation using in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, mariadb, data-integrity

Rails offers a few ways to lock single records. This described in the [Active Record Query Interface guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#locking-records-for-update). However I'm currently in the following scenario where locking existing records won't make the cut:

I have a *Letter* model which has an optional *mailing_nr* attribute. For mailings I'll fetch the maximum *mailing_nr* and add one. Then create a whole bunch of letters in a transaction, because all letters should be saved at the same time, or none at all.

Imagine the scenario where two users generate a mailing at the exact same time. They will both fetch the highest *mailing_nr* (I'll use `6` as an example). When both processes save their records they will end up with the same *mailing_nr*.

How do I prevent the above scenario? I thought of locking down the whole table to prevent reading and writing by other processes. However I'm not aware of any Rails methods that will do this.

Here is my code sample:

```rb
# app/models/letter.rb
def self.create_mailing(template, report, options = {})
  options = options.dup
  options[:mailing_nr] = (Letter.maximum(:mailing_nr) || 0) + 1

  letters = nil
  transaction do
    letters = report.fetch_records.map do |record|
      new_with_template(template, record, options).tap(&:save!)
    end
  end

  letters
end
```

Comment: I think your are looking for [`ActiveRecord::Locking::Pessimistic`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html) to use this you may need to understand the locking mechanisms for your given database for example [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/explicit-locking.html). This would be called as `Letter.lock('YOUR LOCKING CLAUSE')`. **Note I have never actually used this functionality**

Comment: Use `AUTO_INCREMENT`, _not_ max+1 !

Comment: @RickJames As far as I know `AUTO_INCREMENT` doesn't work when you're trying to insert multiple records with the same number. A mailing consists of multiple letters with the same *mailing_nr*. That solution would work if I create a separate *mailings* table, just to increment a number.

Comment: @3limin4t0r - That separate table can have an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  It's the index (usually the `PRIMARY KEY`) that prevents dups.  If you have multiple simultaneous connections there will come a day when two users get the same id with the max+1 technique.  Beware.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Rails Lock](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html) like:

```
letter = Letter.find(1)
letter.with_lock do
    #Do whatever you want, You have only single access here. No two persons can access this at a time 
end
```

**Note** Do give a read to the link provided, because you may find different approach there which may be better for your specific problem.

**Update:** you can use [this gem](https://github.com/mceachen/monogamy) but be warned that may cause deadlock.

Comment: I've updated the question to prevent misunderstandings. `Letter.lock.find(1)` will still only lock the single *Letter* record with *id* 1. The issue is that I'm not updating existing records, but instead created new once based upon the maximum value in a certain column. All other process should wait reading and updating from and to this column until the mailing action is over and new records are added with the new *mailing_nr*.

Comment: Note Your *Update* still only locks 1 row. @3limin4t0r beat me to it